# On two Windows 10 laptops and one Android 7.1.1 phone, with the same wifi, all with Firefox, getting different levels of access to sites

Tags: windows, firefox, internet, android, steam

On two Windows 10 laptops (A and B) and one Android 7.1.1 phone, with the same wifi, getting different levels of access to sites.

And this is sudden.

I can only access this site with A now, but could access with both yesterday, and B can't access StackExchange or the BBC with my wifi, but can do so on another public wifi.

With both laptops, Steam can't update itself, but B did so until tonight or so, and A stopped being able to, from January or so?

Shutting off my Firewalls still doesn't let Steam update. Neither does running as Administrator, in combination with Comparability Modes for earlier Windows versions.

My phone can't access much more than Google sites and Outlook. It seems to be following the pattern as B. Disabling "IPv6" in about:config changes messages from "Cannot Connect to Server" to "Unable to Connect".

---

Any help? Or too specific?

Comment: Have you cleared cache and cookies on these devices? That's usually a good place to start. Second, has your wi-fi router been power-cycled or had its firmware updated lately?

Comment: @FriedWaffle - Thanks! Good idea. Will try tomorrow. Gotta go.

Comment: @FriedWaffle - Router Reboot fixed things~!